# Black box around overlaying images (GD Library)

Tags: php, html, gd

Okay, so i have managed to overlay two images retaining transparency, but now there's a massive black box around the right side of the overlaying image.. it's still transparent, i just need this box gone..

here's my code..

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');

$master = imagecreatefrompng('Master.png');
$month = imagecreatefrompng('Mar.png');

imagealphablending($month,true);

imagealphablending($master,true);

imagecopy($master, $month, 83, 290, 0, 0, imagesx($master), imagesx($master));

imagepng($master, null, 1);

?>
```

I have tried to use imagesavealpha() but that didnt work either.. anyone got any ideas?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
imagecopy($master, ..snip.. imagesx($master), imagesx($master));
                                    ^^^^^^^---should be $month
                                                    ^--- should be 'y'
                                                      ^^^^^^^--- also $month
```

Comment: Sweet,thanks for the help! Surprised i didnt pick up on it... but it's 7 am and i've been up all night with no coffee! :P